# Custom error handling

Tags: joomla, error-handling, joomla2.5

I am developing a component in joomla 2.5, my component sends a request to some url and gets the response object. If i  pass wrong url, joomla takes me to the default page of Error : 500 - No response code found . I want that if user install my component and mistakenly they put wrong url ,  it should show some custom error message/page which should more meaningful to non-programming person rather than taking user to default error page. Is there some way to add this type of functionality in Joomla without editing template/error.php file in core.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an error.php file in your template, if you don't add one and make it look the way you want. also remember that when you turn debugging off you won't get the stack trace etc.

However error 500 indicates something different than that the url does not exist ("wrong URL"), which would be a 404.  500 is an internal server error and you need to check your logs to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: if some other user install my component and some error occur , what i want is  if some error occcur catch that error then instead of going error.php , i create a custom xyz.php file , and user is redirected to that xyz.php file, is it possible ? i would not have access to their template file , how could i edit their error.php file. I only have component files.

Comment: Yes though without knowing what is causing the 500 error it's hard to know what makes sense.

Comment: I used try catch method, i put try on post request function, then echo some message in catch if something goes wrong . Error 500 was caused because in case user type wrong url , response object was not returning  that caused the error.

Comment: Yes that's similar to what happens in JFeed if the http request was bad.